# Converting Pandas dataframe to dictionary renames column headers with spaces

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I've noticed that converting a Pandas dataframe using the `to_dict()` method leads to column names containing spaces to be renamed in the resulting dictionary keys. First off, let me be clear that I understand it is typically poor practice to intentionally include spaces in your dataframe column names. My use case involves updating a `dash-table` via it's `data` attribute, which populates the data table based on it's pre-defined column names specified in the static HTML layout (the column headers need not be updated dynamically, since their order is not dependent on any callbacks). Take the following sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Distance (ft)': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'City': ['Seattle','Portland','Spokane','Everett','Tacoma'],
    'Temp (F)': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})
```

Yields:

```
   Distance (ft)      City  Temp (F)
0              1   Seattle        10
1              2  Portland        20
2              3   Spokane        30
3              4   Everett        40
4              5    Tacoma        50
```

When I attempt to convert this dataframe using `df.to_dict()` where the default for `orient='dict'`, I return what I expect:

```
{'Distance (ft)': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5}, 'City': {0: 'Seattle', 1: 'Portland', 2: 'Spokane', 3: 'Everett', 4: 'Tacoma'}, 'Temp (F)': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 30, 3: 40, 4: 50}}
```

However, using alternative arguments for `orient` such as:

```
df.to_dict('records')
df.to_dict('rows')
```

Both return:

```
[{'_0': 1, 'City': 'Seattle', '_2': 10}, {'_0': 2, 'City': 'Portland', '_2': 20}, {'_0': 3, 'City': 'Spokane', '_2': 30}, {'_0': 4, 'City': 'Everett', '_2': 40}, {'_0': 5, 'City': 'Tacoma', '_2': 50}]
```

Is it possible to return the following without having to perform an intermediate mapping between desired column names and output dictionary keys?

```
[{'Distance (ft)': 1, 'City': 'Seattle', 'Temp (F)': 10}, {'Distance (ft)': 2, 'City': 'Portland', 'Temp (F)': 20}, {'Distance (ft)': 3, 'City': 'Spokane', 'Temp (F)': 30}, {'Distance (ft)': 4, 'City': 'Everett', 'Temp (F)': 40}, {'Distance (ft)': 5, 'City': 'Tacoma', 'Temp (F)': 50}]
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce the issue, what pandas version are you using?

Comment: pandas version 0.24.0

Comment: as @Vaishali mentioned, i cannot reproduce the issue either. i tried the 3 x different `orient` and all worked fine (not renaming the column names). my `pandas` version is `pandas==0.23.4` though

Comment: Weird, this issue just popped up for me after I upgraded to the most recent pandas version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done

```
[y.iloc[0,:].to_dict() for x , y in df.groupby(level=0)]
[{'City': 'Seattle', 'Distance (ft)': 1, 'Temp (F)': 10}, {'City': 'Portland', 'Distance (ft)': 2, 'Temp (F)': 20}, {'City': 'Spokane', 'Distance (ft)': 3, 'Temp (F)': 30}, {'City': 'Everett', 'Distance (ft)': 4, 'Temp (F)': 40}, {'City': 'Tacoma', 'Distance (ft)': 5, 'Temp (F)': 50}]
```

Comment: Thanks! This solves my issue, but it appears to be stemming from the most recent upgrade version of pandas